# cq5/aem url rewriting or mapping dispatcher and apache web server

Tags: webserver, aem, dispatcher, sling

I am new to cq5/aem url re-writing with selectors. I have the following scenarios to achieve. Could you please help me how to do it.

I need to request an URL such as

```
http://localhost:4502/batteries/toyota/corolla/2011/LE/
```

which should convert to

```
http://localhost:4502/content/myprojectroot/project1/en/batteries/search-results.toyota.corolla.2011.LE.html
```

using apache web server/dispatcher configuration and cq5/aem (etc/map). Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a node under `/etc/map` as follows, the filters on the publisher will re-route the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"
          sling:internalRedirect="[/content/myprojectroot/project1/en/batteries/search-results.$1.$2.$3.$4.html]"
          sling:match=".+/batteries/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/"/>
```

This sling.match allows you to match groups, then use the `$1` syntax to capture that match portion to use in the re-route URL.

Then you just need to ensure that the dispatcher allows the initial URL pattern.  Once the dispatcher does its thing it sends the request to the publisher, and then on the publisher the map redirect will occur as the request is processed.

Also see https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/configuring/resource-mapping.html and https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html

Answer (score 0):

use apache mod_rewrite do modify the url hitting the dispachter!

Answer (score 0):

Use Rewrite rule as below on your **Vhost**:

```
RewriteRule ^/batteries/toyota/corolla/2011/LE/ /content/myprojectroot/project1/en/batteries/search-results.toyota.corolla.2011.LE.html [R=301,L]
```